# DataAnnotationsValidator doesn't work with a custom component

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I created this custom component

```html
@inherits InputLabelPers1Base
<div class="text-input">
    <input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes" value="@Value" type="text" placeholder=@InputPlaceHolder @onchange="OnInputValueChanged"  >
    <label for="input1">@LabelValue </label>
</div>
```

that inherits from this class :

```cs
 public class InputLabelPers1Base : InputBase<String>
    {
        
        [Parameter]
        public string InputPlaceHolder { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public string LabelValue { get; set; }

        protected Task OnInputValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            Value = (String)e.Value;

            return ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
        }

        protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, [MaybeNull] out string result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string validationErrorMessage)
        {
            result = value;
            validationErrorMessage = null;
            return true;
        }

      
    }
```

And I added the component to an `EditForm`:
the validation work fine for the built in componant `InputText` but not for my custom component

```html
<div class="ClientCardContainer">
    <EditForm Model="@Client" OnInvalidSubmit="@Save">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
        <div class="ClientInfoGridContainer">
        <InputLabelPerso1 @bind-Value="Client.CL_NOM" LabelValue="Nom/Société" InputPlaceHolder="Nom/Société"></InputLabelPerso1>
        <InputLabelPerso1 @bind-Value="Client.CL_CODE" LabelValue="Code" InputPlaceHolder="Code Client"></InputLabelPerso1>
        <InputLabelPerso1 @bind-Value="Client.CL_VILLE" LabelValue="Ville" InputPlaceHolder="Ville client"></InputLabelPerso1>
      
        <InputText @bind-Value="Client.CL_NOM"></InputText> // **Works Fine**
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
</div>
```

Comment: Plus the save method is alwyas triggered even if the model is not valid

Comment: Because you use OnInvalidSubmit instead of OnValidSubmit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and test...
Comments and explanations in the code...

### InputLabelPers1Base.cs

```cs
    public class InputLabelPers1Base : InputBase<String>
        {
            [Parameter]
            public string InputPlaceHolder { get; set; }
    
            [Parameter]
            public string LabelValue { get; set; }
    
            protected async Task OnInputValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
            {
                // Use the CurrentValueAsString instead of Value 
                // Value = (String)e.Value;
                // You shouldn't call the base class ValueChanged.
                // When you assign the new value to the 
                // CurrentValueAsString property, the code in the 
                // CurrentValue property called by CurrentValueAsString
                // takes care of updating the field bound to your
                // InputLabelPerso1 component

                CurrentValueAsString = e.Value.ToString();
                await Task.CompletedTask;
            }
    
            protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, [MaybeNull] out string result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string validationErrorMessage)
            {
                result = value;
                validationErrorMessage = null;
                return true;
            }
    
    
        }
```

### InputLabelPerso1.razor

```html
    @inherits InputLabelPers1Base
    <div class="text-input">
        <input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes" value="@CurrentValue" type="text" placeholder=@InputPlaceHolder @onchange="OnInputValueChanged">
        <label for="input1">@LabelValue </label>
    </div>
```

### Index.razor

```html
    @page "/"
    @using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
    
    <EditForm Model="@Client" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
        <div class="ClientInfoGridContainer">
            <InputLabelPerso1 @bind-Value="Client.Value1" LabelValue="Nom/Société" InputPlaceHolder="Nom/Société"></InputLabelPerso1>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Client.Value1)" />
    
            <InputText @bind-Value="Client.Value2"></InputText>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Client.Value2)" />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
```

```cs
    @code
        {
           
        private Customer Client = new Customer();
        private void HandleValidSubmit()
        {
            // Called only when the model is valid
            Console.WriteLine("Handled");
        }
        private void HandleInvalidSubmit()
        {
            // Called whenever the model is invalid
            Console.WriteLine("invalid");
        }
    
        public class Customer
        {
            [Required]
            public string Value1 { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Value2 { get; set; }
    
        }
      
    }
```

Comment: why did you create the Parameter 'SelectedValue ' and never  used it ?

Comment: Out of habit, as you have to create a pair of parameters to store the received value and an EventCallback to update the bound value (Client object), thus creating two-way databinding. But here I make no use of it...you can remove it

Comment: @yasseros, I've updated my answer to reflect the reasoning behind your question, which I've dismissed as a mere bad habit. In matter of truth I should not have defined the parameters  'SelectedValue' and 'SelectedValueChanged' at all. They both are not necessary as their equivalent in the base class is used.